Docker error /bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/dnf: not found
I'm working on a password manager project, and I developed on Fedora 40 in a pretty quick way, now I'm trying to make a .exe file to deploy my project on Windows, so I built the .exe file with PyInstaller and I started to write a Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10-slim
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN pip install tk

RUN /usr/bin/dnf install tk-devel #This one

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "PMUID.py"]

firstly, I tried to run this file without the sixth line, I typed docker build -t pmuid-app . on bash, the build process was executed succesfully, but then when I tried to run docker run -it --rm pmuid-app and I get this error:
stroop@fedora-d:~/PMUID$ docker run -it --rm pmuid-app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/PMUID.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

And yeah, I have installed tk inside my .venv python env, honestly, I'm actually upset about this errors from every .exe that I've made, Although I tried a lot of possible solutions, this bug wasn't fixed, anyways, I added new line into Dockerfile, and bash show me this:
stroop@fedora-d:~/PMUID$ docker build -t pmuid-app .
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

Sending build context to Docker daemon  434.9MB
Step 1/8 : FROM python:3.10-slim
 ---> 5f42e6b8b17e
Step 2/8 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d8334c6d0fe9
Step 3/8 : COPY requirements.txt .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 727d1fc33b7f
Step 4/8 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fed50ddeedcd
Step 5/8 : RUN pip install tk
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3dd74195c49d
Step 6/8 : RUN /usr/bin/dnf install tk-devel
 ---> Running in f3d680db3777
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/dnf: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/dnf install tk-devel' returned a non-zero code: 127

My main goal is just make this app reachable to both Linux and Windows, I need to run the .exe succesfully throuh Docker.

Running GUI applications in Docker is complicated and has tricky host-OS dependencies; see Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container?  If your program presents an interactive GUI, you'll probably find it much easier to run without Docker.  Also see the Python Packaging User Guide for standard practices for Python applications.

The standard python images are based on Debian GNU/Linux and use APT as their primary packaging tool, not dnf; also see https://packages.debian.org/ for a list of available packages, including a way to search packages by filename.

Thanks man, and yeah, I was thinking run Ubuntu bash instead fedora bash, that would be better to deploy Docker RUN command
